# What happens to the electron in a beta minus decay?

Tags: electrons, radiation, neutrinos, neutrons, protons

We know that in a beta minus decay the neutron decays into a proton, electron and electron antineutrino. So let's assume we have a vacuum chamber full of free neutrons which after sometime decay in to its decay products.

So when the neutron gets decayed into a proton does the proton capture the electron which was emitted during the decay process? What will happen to all the electrons in that chamber which were emitted during the decay?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about a magic inert chamber, or a real vacuum chamber?

Comment: @JonCuster vacuum chamber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  neutron decay  products will travel in straight paths  if in a vacuum chamber, they will  hit the walls and disappear. In any case,  neutrons cannot be contained in vacuum. Complicated methods are used in [trapping them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracold_neutrons)

Comment: Will the proton also disappear?

Comment: The proton will penetrate a bit the wall , grab an electron and become a hydrogen atom. The original electron of the decay will keep the walls neutral

Comment: if we make the walls postively charged such that it generates a positive electric field? Will it still penetrate?

Comment: It will depend on the energy of the proton. The probability of penetrating the first surface is large. In general you can trap the electron and positron in a magnetic field. The problem is upi cannot trap a source of neutrons in a vacuum chamber so as to wait for their decays.

Comment: Re, "Neutrons can not be contained in vacuum."  I suppose you mean that neutrons do not interact with the _walls_ of a typical vacuum chamber.

Comment: @jameslarge I mean that it is not possible to manipulate neutrons the way one can manipulate charged particles  . The magnetic dipole  interaction is not strong enough to give a handle. Once generated they just follow the momentum they have and either hit the wall and become absorbed or decay,  depending also on their energy.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by annav is correct that the neutron decay products will travel in straight paths in a vacuum chamber; the electron and proton will interact with the walls of the chamber, slow down, and become ordinary matter.  (Most actual neutron traps involve strong magnetic fields, which make the charged particles travel on non-straight paths, but that seems like a minor detail.)

However: because the neutron decay involves three objects, the distribution of energy and momentum among the electron, proton, and neutrino is random.  The total energy released in the decay is roughly 750,000 eV, which is typically shared more-or-less equally between the electron and the neutrino.  However, if the neutrino carries away so much of the energy that the electron and proton together have less that 13 eV, the binding energy of the hydrogen atom, then it is possible for the electron to be immediately captured.  This is called "bound beta decay", $\rm n \to H+\bar\nu_e$. [As of 2014](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.phpro.2013.12.009) this process has not been observed.